# Standalone Java Websocket client NoClassDefFoundError by ContainerProvider

Tags: java, maven, websocket, client, tyrus

I'm new to Java, but I have to use it to do a small WebSocket related project.

So, I installed JDK 1.8.0 and NetBeans 8.1 on my CentOS 7 in a VirtualBox.

I added the *tyrus-standalone-client-jdk 1.12* plug-in in the *pom.xml* to make the standalone Websocket client, and it built fine. However, I ran into the error below:

```
[root@cet7 ~]# java -jar "/root/NetBeansProjects/Switchclient/target/Switchclient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/ContainerProvider
    at org.sample.switchclient.Switchclient.main(Switchclient.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.ContainerProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more

[root@cet7 ~]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

I did a bit more searching and found that the "fully qualified classname of the container implementation of `ContainerProvider` must be listed in the *META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider* file in the implementation JAR file" for the `ServiceLoader` API according to Oracle documentation. So, I added the *serviceloader-maven-plugin* to the pom.xml. The result was that it did generate the *META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider* file, but without any content, and the runtime error continued to persist. I tried to modify the contents bellow manually and re-pack it into a JAR but it did not worked:

1. [org.glassfish.tyrus.container.inmemory.InMemoryContainerProvider](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/blob/master/containers/inmemory/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider)
2. [org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager](https://dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client)

I've attached the Java file and the *pom.xml*. I've worked for hours and haven't a clue what the issue is, so any response to this thread will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

===========LIST1: pom.xml===========

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Switchclient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
            <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>org.sample.switchclient.Switchclient</mainClass>
            </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>eu.somatik.serviceloader-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>serviceloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <services>
                        <param>javax.websocket.ContainerProvider</param>
                    </services>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client-jdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


</project>
```

===========LIST2: Switchclient.java===========
    package org.sample.switchclient;

```
import java.net.URI;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

@ClientEndpoint
public class Switchclient {
    @OnMessage
    public void onRemoteMessage (String message) {
        System.out.println("Received msg: "+message); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebSocketContainer container = null;
        Session session = null;
        try{
            container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            session = container.connectToServer (Switchclient.class, URI.create("ws://localhost:8080/Switchserver/"));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Basically, Tyrus requires **Java EE**. It's the reason you have to list a lot of dependencies in `pom.xml`. If you use Java SE and want to keep your project small, use another different WebSocket client library that depends on only Java SE. For example, **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** (mine).

Just add the following dependency to `pom.xml`,

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
    <artifactId>nv-websocket-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

then try:

```java
import com.neovisionaries.ws.client.*;

public class Switchclient
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        WebSocket websocket = new WebSocketFactory()
            .createSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Switchserver/")
            .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(WebSocket ws, String message) {
                    System.out.println("Received msg: " + message);
                }
            })
            .connect();

        // Don't forget to call disconnect() after use.
        // websocket.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Takahiko and sorry for very late reply. I'd thought I should verify this way first and then repl;y but it turned out I focused on many other points once I got the Tyrus way worked. But it's good to have the  nv-websocket-client solution since it depends only on Java SE. I shell transfer to this solution shortly. Thanks again and Happy New Year ;-)

Comment: Thank you again Takahiko as I tested this client library works fine so far ;-)

Comment: Hi, I am new to java, I use .net. Tyrus requires Java EE. Could you please give some more info or elaborate which component is part of Java EE?

Comment: @gfan [javax.websocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/package-summary.html) package includes classes for WebSocket. The specification is defined as [JSR 356: Java API for WebSocket](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356).

Comment: truly awesome... pity I found it after trying a few other ways

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what exactly caused the problem since I kept trying and problems kept jumping out during the past day. But finally here is it:
Client dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

*at a first glance it seems javax.websocket-client-api should be enough but finally cyber said that ContainerProvider is not impediment*.
Then, all built OK. (with different java codes from my original post, I tried a lot on including the source codes, but codes themselves don't matter that match here while the *environment*  setup matters. They mostly based on the examples of [Tyrus 1.9 user guide](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.9/userguide.%20html) however.)

And the run from the NetBeans by maven was OK, but when I went to use "java -jar Switchclient.jar", same/similar problem jumped out saying problem with "Endpoint".

Finally (as a last try) I copied all those tar files included in the classpath (witch was generated by maven-jar-plugin by specifying "`<addClasspath>true<addClasspath>`" into one directory, and also copied the generated jar file in, then it worked:
*[root@cet7 neededjars]# ls

grizzly-framework-2.3.22.jar        tyrus-client-1.12.jar

grizzly-http-2.3.22.jar             tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.12.jar

grizzly-http-server-2.3.22.jar      tyrus-core-1.12.jar

javax.websocket-api-1.1.jar         tyrus-spi-1.12.jar

javax.websocket-client-api-1.1.jar  tyrus-standalone-client-1.12.jar

Switchclient-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

[root@cet7 neededjars]# java -jar Switchclient-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Received message: Hello world*

That's it, dirty and but worked. and I'm at a new start. Again, I'm really new to java (one of those non-hard-tech guys, just pick it up in case of need); and it showed me the complicity of the community based development, especially in the case the technology is relatively new. dependencies and pitfall everywhere. That's is one part of the nature I guess...